# How to print list one after the other in a vertical order in text file in python

Tags: python

```
import sys
sys.stdout = filename
fin = fout
fout = fin
```

### Expected Output

['I','am'] 
['my','name']

Comment: Show expected output to confirm what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension puts the output to a list. You probably want to print it instead?

```
for word in words:
    print(word)
```